# Consider the set of real numbers with the topology generated by $B=\{(n,n+1] | n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Which sets are both open and closed?

Tags: general-topology

I know that by definition $\emptyset$ is open and closed.

I think (3,4) is open and [4,6) is closed. Alternatively, $(3,5]$ is also open and closed as it could be written as the union of two open sets, $(3,4] \cup (4,5)$. Similarly with $(8,\infty)$.

I'm struggling to get this material down, and I think putting numbers to the basis/making a concrete example would help, hence this problem. Am I off?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(3,4)$ is not open: if $x\in(3,4)$, there is no $(n-1,n]$ in $B$ such that $x\in(n-1,n]\subseteq(3,4)$. $[4,6)$ is not closed: every open nbhd of $6$ must contain the basic open set $(5,6]$, and $(5,6]\cap[4,6)\ne\varnothing$, so $6$ is a limit point of $[4,6)$ and therefore must be in the closure of $[4,6)$. You should try to show, in fact, that the closure of $[4,6)$ is $(3,6]$.

Note that $B$ is actually a partition of $\Bbb R$: the members of $B$ are pairwise disjoint, and their union is $\Bbb R$. For convenience let $U_n=(n-1,n]$. The open sets in this topology are the unions of members of $B$, so each open set can be described by a subset of $\Bbb Z$: for $A\subseteq\Bbb Z$ let

$$U(A)=\bigcup_{n\in A}U_n\;.$$

- Verify that $\Bbb R\setminus U(A)=U(\Bbb Z\setminus A)$ for each $A\subseteq\Bbb Z$. Then explain why the closed sets in this topology are precisely the open sets: every open set is closed, and every closed set is open.